# How to compare concentration ratios

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I did a spectrometry measurement with the evaluation of the concentration of an element. For the element of interest I've two peaks (with normal distribution).

$ C_1 ± \sigma_1 $    where $ \sigma_1 = \sqrt{C_1} $ and number of counts *n*

$ C_2 ± \sigma_2 $  where $ \sigma_2 = \sqrt{C_2} $ and number of counts *m*

The concentration is evaluated by the ratio between counts $ C_i $ and mass $ m ± \sigma_m $ and time $t$ (with negligible measurement error).

$ A_i = C_i/(m*t) $  and the measurement uncertainty is $\sigma_{Ai} = f ( \sigma_i  ;\sigma_m) $

At the end I quantify the ratio $ R=A_1/A_2 $ with $\sigma_R = f ( \sigma_{a1}  ;\sigma_{a2}) $

I measured the ratio **R** for three different samples of soil (they were sampled in different places.)

soil *s1* -->  $ R_{s1} ± \sigma_{s1} $

soil *s2* -->  $ R_{s2} ± \sigma_{s2} $

soil *s3* -->  $ R_{s3} ± \sigma_{s3} $

**question** I have to compare these three results to evaluate if they are  similar or different. How could I make this comparison?

How could I make the comparison between the soil *s1* and the average(*s2*;*s3*)? one sample *t-test*?

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you have more than one measurement of A1 and A2 for each of the soils? Or are you looking for a theoretical, propagation-of-error type of answer?

Comment: Well...I've only one measurement for each soil. I need to compare only the three single measurement for the three soils.

Comment: Because of there are only ratios (between counts and mass; between concentration $A_1$ and $A_2$ ) , the final cumulative uncertainty is quantified with this formula


$ ( \sigma_f / f )^2 = ( \sigma_h / h )^2 +( \sigma_g / g )^2  $ 
with covariance terms equal to zero.

the formula is used to quantify the uncertainties $\sigma_{Ai}$ and $\sigma_R$

Answer (score 2):

With only one measurement for each soil, it's too easy for an error in pipetting or an unsuspected problem with introducing a sample into the spectrometer to give you a falsely positive difference between the soils. You couldn't prove to me (or to a reputable journal) that there are differences between soils with only 1 measurement each. The *t*-test (or any other statistical test) in general requires more measurements than samples that you are comparing. Otherwise, there is no statistical way to separate differences among samples from practical measurement error.

In terms of theoretical propagation-of-error analysis, your second comment seems to suggest that you are implicitly assuming that errors are proportional to observed values, which is quite reasonable in many applications. In that case, note that working with the logarithm of *R* neatly changes all the pesky ratios and products in your formulas into differences and sums, and provides a simple sum of error terms (on the log scale) for estimating the final error from the (log-scale) errors of the individual types of measurements. But that theoretical analysis, although potentially informative, can't overcome the practical limitation of having only one measurement for each soil.

Comment: Thank! in Your answer there are two important points:
1) the evaluation of the uncertainty. Your suggestion about log transformation is advantageous. The uncertainty of the concentration A could be fixed with the combined standard deviation.


2) the problem of only one measurement for the soil could be insurmountable because of the small amount of each sample.